# Is SelectionSort faster than QuickSort in the worst case scenario?

Tags: sorting

Is SelectionSort faster than QuickSort in the worst-case scenario?

QuickSort, in the worst case, allegedly does $n^2$ comparisons. And SelectionSort, if I am not mistaken, always does $n^2/2$ operations. By that logic, there should be a permutation for an array of any size for which SelectionSort is faster than QuickSort. Am I missing something?

Comment: That is why we use randomized quicksort in which the pivot is randomly selected. You should be very unlucky to reach that.

Comment: Do you have pointers for the figures $n^2$ and $n^2/2$?